# How do I get a dynamic value for a WHERE query into a data grid in ASP.NET/C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a web page that needs to display a data grid with data pulled from a database. I am building this in MS VS as an ASP.NET/C# application. In my view, I am using a GridView element. I have already connected the GridView to the database and it's pulling the data correctly.

However, I need to restrict the data being pulled by the user ID so only the data for a given user will be displayed. I know how to hard code the user ID value in the GridView element design UI but I need the value to be dynamic. Specifically, it will be read from the url that the user enters.

So what I am trying to accomplish is to extract the user ID from the url string (not the issue, I know how to do this) and then add it dynamically as the WHERE query value in my database query string. It should look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [DatabaseTableName] WHERE ([customerID] = IDExtractedFromURL)
```

How can I add the dynamic customer ID value ("IDExtractedFromURL") to the GridView element? Is it possible to pass it as a variable? If so, what's the syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

In common, I'd not pass user IDs in query string, but to accomplish what you want, I'd do:

1) get user ID from query-string

`var userId = int.Parse(this.Request.QueryString("userId"));`

2) add `where` filter to your SQL

`sql += "\n WHERE [CustomerID] = @userId"`;

3) add parameter to your grid data source (wherever it's located)

`dataSource.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("userId", TypeCode.Int32, userId)))`

Comment: I'm afraid I need smaller steps. I am mostly working with the Design part so I don't actually know where your code would go. In Source view, my GridView is defined like so:

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="siteId" DataSourceID="MyDBConnect">`

The data source looks like this:

`<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MyDBConnect" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE ([customerId] = @customerId)">`

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit enter before I was finished typing the code. I added it afterwards. 

So is there a way to make the `WHERE ([customerId] = @customerId)` part dynamic? I have tried adding a model class with a setter and getter for the ID and then referencing it in the WHERE query like so: `WHERE ([customerId] = MyModel.GetCustomerID)` but that didn't work.

Comment: yes, there's a way to make SQL dynamic, it's just a string. First of all, define your `SelectCommand` in codebehind in c#. `MyDBConnect.SelectCommand = "select * from [MyTable]"`, then check if user id is present in query-string: `Request.QueryString["userId"]!=null`. Then use code posted in my answer

Comment: by the way, it's considered a very bad practice to have SQL code in .aspx

Comment: Another by-the-way: here's a basic example of what you want to achieve (very similar, but with list-box). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.querystringparameter.querystringfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx It uses `QueryStringParameter` of sqldatasource

Comment: But I discourage you from using this approach, see my comment about SQL in aspx.